# msal in React SPA - use access token received from AcquireTokenRedirect

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

I have a React SPA and I'm using msal to authenticate Microsoft users using loginRedirect. After the login, I'm acquiring an access token silently using acquireTokenSilent to call a web API. When acquiring the access token fails and interaction is required, I'm using acquireTokenRedirect.

When I use acquireTokenRedirect, what I see is:
1. The user is redirected to login.microsoftonline.com. 
2. A 302 response is returned with Location header that contains the redirect url + the access token. 
3. A GET request to my redirect url - my callback gets called. 
4. Another redirect to my app root.

This last redirect makes my app to be served again and I lose the access token from the state of the app. In addition, I lost the ability to redirect the user to a specific route.

Getting the access token:

```
getAccessToken = async () => {
    let accessTokenRequest = { scopes: [...]
    };
    try {
      var accessTokenResponse = await 
      this.authAgent.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest);
      return accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      const errorCode = error.name;
      if (errorCode === "consent_required" || errorCode === "interaction_required") {
        await this.authAgent.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
      }

      throw error;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid the extra redirect, what I needed to do is set the "navigateToLoginRequestUrl" param in Auth config to false. This solves my problem.

Comment: You can mark it as the answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). It will be beneficial to others.

Answer (score -1):

You can also acquire token with a pop-up window. Here are the [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token) between `acquireTokenPopup` and `acquireTokenRedirect` methods.

When you use `acquireTokenPopup` method, refer to this sample.

```
const accessTokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["user.read"]
}

userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
    // Acquire token silent success
    // call API with token
    let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Acquire token silent failure, send an interactive request.
    if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
        userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
            // Acquire token interactive success
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Acquire token interactive failure
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    console.log(error);
});
```

When you use `acquireTokenRedirect` method, you need to register the redirect callback.

```
function authCallback(error, response) {
    //handle redirect response
}

userAgentApplication.handleRedirectCallback(authCallback);

const accessTokenRequest: AuthenticationParameters = {
    scopes: ["user.read"]
}

userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
    // Acquire token silent success
    // call API with token
    let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
}).catch(function (error) {
    //Acquire token silent failure, send an interactive request.
    console.log(error);
    if (error.errorMessage.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1) {
        userAgentApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(accessTokenRequest);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the popup method, however, we chose to specifically to use the Redirect method for a couple of reasons. I did register a callback afgets called with the 302 response, however, after it gets called, the browser redirects to my home page and the access token is lost from my SPA state.

Comment: @HadarRomashkano Can't you get access token in authCallback method? `function authCallback(error, response) {
    //handle redirect response
}`

Comment: I do get it and save it in the state (context) of the app, but then there's another redirect done because the response from the login service is 302. Once the redirects happen, my app is reloaded with a new state (context) that does not contain the token.

Comment: To summary, what happens is: 1. I call acquireTokenRedirect - the user is redirected to login.microsoftonline.com. 2. I get a 302 response with Location header that contains my redirect url + the access token. 3. I see a call to my redirect url + my callback is called. 4. There's another redirect to my app root. Why does this last redirect happens? Can I avoid it somehow?