# How to acquire token with MSAL acquireTokenRedirect()?

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use msal to acquire token with the redirect method.

I have the following function:

```
function acquireTokenRedirect() {
  const params = {
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/',
    scopes: ['user.read']
  };
  console.log('Acquire token via redirect');
  msal.acquireTokenRedirect(params);
}
```

And the callback:

```
msal.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
  console.log('Redirect call back is called');
});
```

When I call the method, this is what I get in Chrome console:

```
Acquire token via redirect
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/admin/
Redirect call back is called
GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/
```

Why does it redirect to `http://localhost:8080/` when I specifically tell it to redirect to `http://localhost:8080/admin/`?

MSAL is configured to use redirectURI: `http://localhost:8080/admin/`, and the same redirect is specified in the Azure portal for the project.

In comparison, `msal.loginRedirect()` redirects to the correct URI.

Comment: From which page, you are calling acquireTokenRedirect() function? Is it from :8080 or :8080/admin? Also, why aren't you using acquireTokenSilent() instead? Do you have any special requirement?

Comment: There is nothing at :8080 all code is at :8080/admin. My question is about acquireTokenRedirect, not acquireTokenSilent. I want to know why it's not redirecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is related to the solution in this issue :

> To avoid the extra redirect, what I needed to do is set the
>   "**navigateToLoginRequestUrl**" param in Auth config to false. This solves
>   my problem.

Reference : [msal in React SPA - use access token received from AcquireTokenRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735892/msal-in-react-spa-use-access-token-received-from-acquiretokenredirect)

Let me know if that helps